# Closing/Restarting ssh session kills programs running on that session?

Tags: ssh, terminal, tty, session

I am using the web console to ssh to an aws instance. I then start an xrdp session BUT the session does not go over ssh.

However, when I restart or stop this ssh session everything I have run within this session gets killed too (xrdp for instance), even if I have forked it to the background with "&"
I don't know if this is expected behavior or related to the ssh over browser session. Ideas for fixing this and not killing each program within this session would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expeceted behaviuor since when the terminal controlling process quits, it sends `SIGHUP` to all of its children to notify them, that the terminal has hanged up. How the `SIGHUP` is handled by a child process depends only on child process. Putting a process to background does not block signals, it just detaches the child process from the terminal. To block the *hang up signal* you should run your program with `nohup`, eg. `nohup myprogram &`. That should do the job in most cases.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot :)